# Still hacking anyway – TeX at the camp

Tags: discussion, conferences

In five days the hacker camp [SHA2017](https://sha2017.org/) will start. The name means "Still Hacking Anyway", and it is part of a series of hacker camps happening every four years. This year it will be in the Netherlands, and we expect more than 3500 people attending.

DANTE members (Doris, Moss, Martin, Jonas, Stefan) will be there, with some TeX-Friends, making workshops and celebrating LaTeX.

More information can be read here:

- German: [TeXwelt.de](http://texwelt.de/blog/latex-dante-camp/)
- English:  [TeX talk](http://tex-talk.net/2017/07/latex-dante-camp/)

There are a few tickets left, and one free ticket from our team (DANTE provided 6 tickets).

Anybody who would like to join, let us know!

And if it happens that you are there anyway, visit us. :-)

Comment: If i would have the time, i would love to go with you guys.

Comment: Argh, I'm not in AMS in those dates. Otherwise would be real fun to meet you guys.